# During Fetch Method changed to Options with 200 status and succes fetch

Tags: reactjs, http, protocols, fetch-api

I have got problem with Fetch in React, I'm using this code, and i should recive this status
http://docs.recruitment-api.pyt1.stg.jmr.pl/#
But i receive 
Succes:  {"message":"The method is not allowed for the requested URL."}
with Status 200 OK
Also methods change to OPTIONS
http://prntscr.com/lu0lat

```
submitToApi = e => {
e.preventDefault();
const url =
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://recruitment-api.pyt1.stg.jmr.pl/login';
const data = {
  login: this.state.email,
  password: this.state.password
};
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => console.log('Succes: ', JSON.stringify(response)))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error));
this.setState({
  email: '',
  password: ''
});
```

};

Comment: Is that something you are getting error in Console?

Comment: Succes: {"message":"The method is not allowed for the requested URL."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your react/fetch code. 
You bypass CORS, but probably the api on .pyt1.stg.jmr.pl is understanding it and returning you the response with {"message":"The method is not allowed for the requested URL."}

**EDIT:** try to run fetch part from NodeJS to verify

Comment: how to run it with Node?

Comment: `app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.headers("Allow-Control-Access-Origin","*");
    res.header("Allow-Control-Access-Methods","*");
    next();
})`

Try this in node it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure if OP owns the API. Maybe it belongs to someone else

Answer (score -1):

In your backend micro services, add header to allow the methods.

`Allow-Control-Access-Methods,"*"`

Eg: In NodeJs.

```
res.headers("Allow-Control-Access-Methods","*");
```

Comment: So, the solution is to change some server setting in backend? If yes, I can't do anything more, I'm not administrator of http://recruitment-api.pyt1.stg.jmr.pl/login